# Is this polite or condescending?

Tags: communication, work-environment, human-resources, manager

A supervisor requested that I forward her a log, which I sent her immediately. She then asked for the same in a different format, which I sent immediately. 30 minutes later the supervisor stated that she did not receive the new format, but before I could verify if and what was sent, she sent me the following:

**"I'm so sorry you can't seem to understand when something is politely asked of you, you cannot simply comply."**

So is she really being polite or condescending?

Comment: I feel there's a lot of context missing here.

Comment: SHOUTING IN QUESTION TITLES OFFENDS ME.

Comment: What kind of document was this and what formats were involved? I could see this being halfway reasonable if this was some type of specialty data (e.g. 3d object specification data or satellite telemetry data) that the average person might not have the right software to view except when delivered in a special format.

Comment: a table in Word format

Comment: Offended at what?  She's got some problem on her end, it's a misunderstanding that's causing her to blame you.

Comment: Your boss is an entitled idiot. Being a boss does not allow someone to lack the  basics of respect towards someone.

Comment: I concur everyone deserves respect no matter what position you hold.

Comment: Whether it would offend or not is irrelevant. What is relevant is that your boss's misinterpretation of what happened needs to be corrected.  I would send back an email with the email that I sent earlier. In the email I would mention that perhaps she missed seeing this so you are forwarding it a second time.   If she is trying to prove a performance issue then you have this email to fall back on showing that you did as requested and that you responded to her accusation politely and professionally. If she was just in a bad mood, this will clear up the issue and correct her impression of you. .

Answer (score 7):

No it wouldn't offend me, it might puzzle me a bit and make me question motivations, but I'd need more than that to be offended.

I'd just check that it had in fact been sent, and resend it with 'Sorry if there has been any misunderstanding, I did send this as requested (email attached) and am resending now. Please acknowledge receipt. Regards.'